# Docker "executable file not found in $PATH" even though it is added to the path in the base image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to adapt this image, https://hub.docker.com/r/micromdm/scep, to run the `scepclient` rather than the `scepserver`. The `Dockerfile` for the image is:

```
FROM alpine:3.6

COPY ./build/scepserver-linux-amd64 /usr/bin/scepserver
COPY ./build/scepclient-linux-amd64 /usr/bin/scepclient

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["scepserver"]
```

I would like the `ENTRYPOINT` to be `["scepclient"]` instead of `["scepserver"]`, which I attempted to do using the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM micromdm/scep

ENTRYPOINT ["scepclient"]
```

However, if I build this using `docker build . --tag loadtest` and try to run it I get the following error:

```
> docker run loadtest
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"scepclient\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

I thought that executables added to your `PATH` in the base image (`micromdm/scep`) would also be available in the 'derived' image, but this seems not to be the case, and I wasn't able to get much of a better understanding of this from https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from.

How can I use the `micromdm/scep` image but run `scepclient` instead of `scepserver`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation on the dockerhub page you need to compile scep youself and build the docker image yourself. https://hub.docker.com/r/micromdm/scep

After pulling the scep docker image via

```
docker pull micromdm/scep
```

you can inspect it via

```
docker history micromdm/scep
    IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
    143554922979        17 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/scep"]                0B
    <missing>           17 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  VOLUME [/depot]              0B
    <missing>           17 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 8080/tcp              0B
    <missing>           17 months ago       /bin/sh -c apk --no-cache add curl unzip && …   6.84MB
    <missing>           17 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV SCEP_VERSION=v1.0.0      0B
    <missing>           21 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh"]              0B
    <missing>           21 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:df48d6d6df42a0138…   3.99MB
```

As you can see none of the layers mention the copy of the scep binaries. But it refers to the scep binary in /. However there is no client binary in the / folder. I recommend you check out the associated git repository and build scep and the docker image as described on dockerhub (https://hub.docker.com/r/micromdm/scep).

**Compiling**

To compile the SCEP client and server, there are a few requirements.

You must have a Go compiler. The compiler is normally in the golang package.
You must have a shell variable set for $GOPATH. This is a directory used by the Go compiler and utilities for all Go projects.
Once all of those are set, clone the repository with go get github.com/micromdm/scep
Install dependencies: make deps
Compile the server and client binaries: make build The binaries will be compiled in the build/ folder.

**docker build**

```
docker build -t working/scep:latest .
```

**docker run**

```
docker run -it --rm -v /path/to/ca/folder:/depot micromdm/scep:latest ca -init
```

**building on that image**

next you can alter the Entrypoint as you already described. But this time you will use the newly created working/scep image in your FROM statement.

```
FROM working/scep

ENTRYPOINT ["scepclient"]
```

Comment: I went into the container using `docker run -it --rm micromdm/scep /bin/ash` and indeed there is a `./scep` binary, which is the SCEP server, but no `/usr/bin/scepclient`. Does this mean that the `Dockerfile` posted at https://hub.docker.com/r/micromdm/scep/dockerfile does not reflect the actual image?

Comment: Oh, I didn't the binary in /. Thanks for the correction. I will update the answer.
"Does this mean that the Dockerfile posted at hub.docker.com/r/micromdm/scep/dockerfile does not reflect the actual image?" Yes! That can happen when the build is not triggered via a CI/CD tool and pushed to dockerhub based on the content of the associated git repository.